# Android: Notification to call Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I can get the Notification to call an activity by setting ***PendingIntent*** and using ***setLastestEventInfo()***. What if I want to call to a particular fragment, is that possible? Are the any methods that I can override? As far as I know fragments don't work with intent directly, but need to be hosted by activity.

Comment: No, you can't. What if the fragment isn't instantiated? Instead, send it to the hosting activity, and it can dispatch it to the fragment, or create it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the full class name of the Fragment (`MyFragment.class.getName()`) along as an extra in the Intent. Then, have a hosting Activity which receives the intent, and displays the Fragment given as the extra, something like this:

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_CLASS = "fragment_class";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String fragmentClass = i.getStringExtra(FRAGMENT_CLASS);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fragmentClass)) {
        Fragment toDisplay = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentClass);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.my_root_container, toDisplay, null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i thought about it, but was hoping the might be a solution that would deal with fragment directly. oh, well...

Comment: Fragments aren't standalone, they are designed to attach to an Activity.